# Searching string nested array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a question regarding nested array

```
dd($this->forest);

it give me this:

array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 12
    "location" => 'east'
    "type" => 'reservation'
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "location" => 'west'
    "type" => 'rainforest'
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "location" => 'north'
    "type" => 'rainforest'
  ]
]
```

so I want to search 'swamp' and 'mangrove' like "type" => 'swamp' or "type" => 'mangrove' but these type is not in the array of $this->forest. So, I have used in_array to sort it out.

```
$this->typeOfForest = '';

foreach($this->forest as $item){
  if(!in_array('swamp', $item)){
    $this->typeOfForest = 'swamp_not_found';
    break;
  }
  elseif(!in_array('mangrove', $item)){
    $this->typeOfForest = 'mangrove_not_found';
    break;
  }
}

dd($this->typeOfForest);
```

but when I dd($this->typeOfForest);
it will not set as $this->typeOfForest = 'swamp_not_found'; instead $this->typeOfForest = 'mangrove_not_found';

Also, when I insert new data 'swamp' into array $this->forest; and run again in_array function it will give me $this->typeOfForest = 'swamp_not_found'; instead of $this->typeOfForest = 'mangrove_not_found';

Thank you!

Comment: What if both swap and mangrove didn't exist?

Comment: `in_array` function doesn't work with multidimensional array

Comment: @nice_dev yeah both swap and mangrove does not exist originally, so i wanted to check if both are exist in the multi dimensional array.

Comment: @HarviDent what function should i use to check if both swamp and mangrove exist in multi dimensional array?

Comment: @quezera Yes but my question is what should be the output?

Answer (score 0):

You are using in_array function, it just searches for a given value in every index of the array, But as you have a 2D array, So in_array cant find any index with value JUST 'swamp', so your first IF condition becomes TRUE.
You can do like this:

```
$this->typeOfForest = '';
foreach($this->forest as $item){

   if ($item['type'] == 'swamp'){
      $typeOfForest='swamp found';
      break;
   }
   elseif($item['type'] == 'mangrove'){
     $typeOfForest='mangrove found';
      break;
   }
}
  var_dump($this->typeOfForest);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the `in_array` function does not work with a multidimensional array. You need to use the `array_column` function to get all the types and then just do a lookup.

```
$this->typeOfForest = null;
$types = array_column($this->forest,'type');
if(in_array('swamp', $types)){
    $typeOfForest = 'swamp found';
}elseif(in_array('mangrove', $types)){
    $typeOfForest = 'mangrove found';
}
var_dump($this->typeOfForest);
```

Comment: array_column is really good, this is new to me. Thank you for that knowledge, this works for me, because that $typeOfForest is needed in another functions. Not needing loop is a save for me. Thank you